# How to create a data structure with depth 2kb and width of 32 bit in verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How to create a data structure with depth 2kb and width of 32 bit in verilog or systemverilog

Answer (score 0):

If you want a memory of 2KB with 4 Byte words, you need only declare it as such:

`reg [31:0] mem [0:511]; // Or use logic instead of reg for the type in SystemVerilog`

Here the first part is the type and the width (31 to 0 inclusive) and then the variable name (`mem`) followed by the memory size (I am assuming you want KiB, not just KB, ie 1024 not 100).

To access a word of the memory, just use `mem[addr]` format. If you want the memory to by byte addressable, youll have to do more work or declare the memory differently.

Answer (score 0):

@Unn's answer is correct for static data or routing a signal, but it's missing the control signals of a full memory.

You'll want to declare your structure as `reg [31:0] mem [511:0];` (as Unn mentioned). You'll also want some way to change the data. Note that I flipped the index order for the memory size (just personal preference).

If all of your data structure changes at the same time, you can use the following:

```
reg [31:0] mem [511:0];
reg [31:0] mem_input [511:0];
wire mem_we;
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    mem <= mem_we ? mem_input : mem ;
end
```

If you only want to change parts of the data, one option would be to allow for every 32-bit word to be changed each clock cycle. This will require more routing, but allows for the data to be changed in parallel. In this case you'll want the following:

```
reg [31:0] mem [511:0];
reg [31:0] mem_input [511:0];
wire [511:0] mem_we;
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    for (i=0; i<512; i=i+1)
        mem[i] <= mem_we[i] ? mem_input [i] : mem [i];
end
```

Another option would be to use addressing to change the values. You'll only be able to change one 32-bit word at a time, but you may save on routing.

```
reg [31:0] mem [511:0];
reg [31:0] mem_input;
wire [8:0] mem_addr;
wire mem_we;
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    mem <= mem;
    if (mem_we) mem[mem_addr] <= mem_input;
end
```

`mem_we` is the memory "write-enable" - assert it to write to the memory (either as a whole in 1 and 3, or per-word in 2).
`mem_input` is the input (new value) to the memory.
`mem_addr` is the word to be changed in 3 (a value between 0 and 511).

Comment: Well, the op did just ask for the data structure, not the entire implementation; but thanks for spelling it out :P
Note that the `mem <= mem;` line in the last implementation (which is usually closest to what youd have) is unneeded and can slow down simulation (barring good optimization which might or might not happen), `mem` will retain its value anyway and doesnt need to be reassigned.

Comment: Hence my quoting of your answer :P The only reason I felt I had to expand is because so many people assume that declaring a `reg` alone (without any other logic) makes a memory.